# How to get the object id in PyMongo after an insert?

Tags: mongodb, insert, pymongo

I'm doing a simple insert into Mongo...

```
db.notes.insert({ title: "title", details: "note details"})
```

After the note document is inserted, I need to get the object id immediately. The result that comes back from the insert has some basic info regarding connection and errors, but no document and field info.

I found some info about using the update() function with upsert=true, I'm just not sure if that's the right way to go, I have not yet tried it.

Answer (score 100):

One of the cool things about MongoDB is that the ids are generated client side.

This means you don't even have to ask the server what the id was, because you told it what to save in the first place. Using pymongo the return value of an insert will be the object id. Check it out:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> collection = pymongo.Connection()['test']['tyler']
>>> _id = collection.insert({"name": "tyler"})
>>> print _id.inserted_id 
4f0b2f55096f7622f6000000
```

Comment: Good answer, though I'd suggest the use of `_id` or `id_` as the name. I don't use `id` much in python, but it's probably a good habit not to use built-in function names.

Comment: In modern versions we should use  .inserted_id attribute.
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one

Answer (score 45):

The answer from Tyler does not work for me.

Using `inserted_id` works

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> collection = pymongo.Connection()['test']['tyler']
>>> db_result = collection.insert({"name": "tyler"})
>>> print(db_result)
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x0A7EABCD>
>>> print(db_result.inserted_id)
5acf02400000000968ba447f
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as Tyler's, except that the variable names changed and there is an extra print statement. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Todd Tyler's answer was changed to support the new syntax 3 years after this post was made

Answer (score 19):

It's better to use insert_one() or insert_many() instead of insert(). Those two are for the newer version. You can use inserted_id to get the id.

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
myDB = myclient["myDB"]
userTable = myDB["Users"]
userDict={"name": "tyler"}

_id = userTable.insert_one(userDict).inserted_id
print(_id)
```

Or

```
result = userTable.insert_one(userDict)
print(result.inserted_id)
print(result.acknowledged)
```

If you need to use insert(), you should write like the lines below

```
_id = userTable.insert(userDict)
print(_id)
```

Answer (score 13):

Newer PyMongo versions depreciate `insert`, and instead `insert_one` or `insert_many` should be used. These functions return a `pymongo.results.InsertOneResult` or `pymongo.results.InsertManyResult` object.

With these objects you can use the `.inserted_id` and `.inserted_ids` properties respectively to get the inserted object ids.

Find out more about [`insert_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one), [`insert_many`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many), and [`pymongo.results.InsertOneResult`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult) at the [pymongo docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

**updated; removed previous because it wasn't correct**

It looks like you can also do it with `db.notes.save(...)`, which returns the _id after it performs the insert.

See for more info:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

Comment: Sorry, was a  bit confused by pymongo--updated answer which should work.

Comment: Note that save(D) is actually a driver-side convenience method for either insert(D) or update(D._id, D) depending on whether or not D has an _id field (insert if it doesn't, update if it does)

Answer (score 1):

```
some_var = db.notes.insert({ title: "title", details: "note details"})
print(some_var.inserted_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assigne it to some variable:

```
someVar = db.notes.insert({ title: "title", details: "note details"})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID after an Insert in Python, just do like this:

```
doc = db.notes.insert({ title: "title", details: "note details"})
return str(doc.inserted_id) # This is to convert the ObjectID (type of doc.inserted_id into string)
```